# How do I dynamically specify a file in DOS?

Tags: c#, ftp, dos

I am trying to use c# in .net to run dos commands to ftp a a file. Technically, it calls a BAT file which calls a CMD file which executes the DOS code. It was up to the CMD file. The CMD fiel will work if I hardcode the path, but I need to dynamically specify the path of the file.

BAT File...

```
ftp.exe -s:%~dp0\mycmdfile.cmd
```

And in the cmd file...

```
open <my ost>
<my user name>
<my pw>
quote site cyl pri=1 sec=1 lrecl=1786 blksize=0 recfm=fb retpd=30
put <here is where I need the dynamic path> + localfilename remotefilename
```

quit

Answer (score 1):

I would add to Zachary that you can refer to command line vars inside bat with %1, %2, and so on.

`%~dp0` syntax is only available from Windows 2000 (if I remember it right). To refer to files from another directory just change to a directory just `cd` to that directory and then invoke command from it.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass in arguments to a batch files.  If memory serves me right, you pass them in by putting them after the call to the batch file and using space delimiters (e.g. C:\mycmd.bat Var1 Var2).  You can then use those to reconstruct your file path.