# How do I specify a relative local file path in DOS?

Tags: dos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I dynamically specify a file in DOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953027/how-do-i-dynamically-specify-a-file-in-dos)

I am using c#.NET 2.0 to execute DOS commands to ftp a file. All works except for 1 thing, in the cmd file I call, it runs a PUT statement. Right now the put statement has a hardcoded local file path. I need to specify a dynamic path. I've tried

```
put %~dp0\myfile.DTL myfile.dtl
```

but it says it can't find the file.

Right now the .NET code calls a BAT file which only exist to call the CMD file. Interestingly, the BAT file DOES successfully use a relative path in its call to the CMD file:

```
ftp.exe -s:%~dp0\oit.cmd
```

However, I can't get that relative path to wrok in the cmd file:

```
open <my host> 
<user name> 
<password> 
put <hardcoded path that needs to be relative path>localfilename remotefilename
```

I'll bever know where it will exist so I just need to grab whatever local directorey the file is in.

Answer (score 0):

Relative is "." (dot).

Can you post the exact situation? What directory are you in, and where is the file?

Be careful with the "~" char ... it has a special meaning for DOS files (8.3 notation)

Comment: Right now the .NET code calls a BAT file which only exist to call the CMD file. Interestingly, the BAT file DOES successfully use a relative path in its call to the CMD file:

ftp.exe -s:%~dp0\oit.cmd

However, I can't get that relative path to wrok in the cmd file:

open <my host>
<user name>
<password>
put <hardcoded path that needs to be relative path>localfilename remotefilename

Comment: Ohhh .. so the % sign indicates that dp0 is a variable in the DOS shell. You have to know the actual value. You can add an ECHO command in the BAT file for that

Comment: Add the following line to the bat file before the ftp
ECHO %~dp0%

Comment: Not needed. 
"%~dp0 is only available within a batch file and expands to the drive letter and path in which that batch file is located (which cannot change). It is obtained from %0 which is the batch file's name."
http://www.computerhope.com/forum/index.php?topic=54333.0

Answer (score -2):

Use `System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()` to get the current (working) folder.

Alternatively, if you want the path relative to your .EXE file, you can use `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CodeBase` to get full path to your .EXE file, then use `System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName()` to get the directory name of that path.

After that, you can use `System.IO.Path.Combine` to get absolute path out of relative:

```
string absPath = Path.Combine( @"c:\working\folder", @"sub\folder\file.ext" );
// absPath == "c:\working\folder\sub\folder\file.ext

// Works with double-dot too:
string absPath2 = Path.Combine( @"c:\working\folder", @"..\up\file.ext" );
// absPath == "c:\working\up\file.ext
```

Comment: Thank you, but I really would need the DOS code which would receive this.

Comment: It is a DOS question not C#